# Execute between query in PHP

Tags: php, yii

I am a beginner in php. 
This is the function:

```
public function actionGetreport() {
    $date=$_POST['daterange'];
    $daterange=explode("to",$date);
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    //print_r($name);die();
    $connection = Yii::$app->getDb();
    $command = $connection->createCommand($name)->where(
        ['between', 'InsertedDate', $daterange[0], $daterange[1]]
    );
    //filter||and

    $Result = $command->queryall();
    print_r($Result);die();         
}
```

Here, `$name` has select query and I want to use that query to get info between daterange.
I am getting error like:

```
Exception 'yii\base\UnknownMethodException' with message 'Calling unknown method: yii\db\Command::where()' 

in D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Component.php:294

Stack trace:
#0 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\backend\modules\report\controllers\ReportController.php(31): yii\base\Component->__call('where', Array)
#1 [internal function]: backend\modules\report\controllers\ReportController->actionGetreport()
#2 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\InlineAction.php(57): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#3 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(157): yii\base\InlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
#4 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(528): yii\base\Controller->runAction('getreport', Array)
#5 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(103): yii\base\Module->runAction('report/report/g...', Array)
#6 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(386): yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))
#7 D:\xampp\htdocs\oms\index.php(17): yii\base\Application->run()
#8 {main}
```

Comment: What is the actual error/problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following simple command

Add the following code to your controller action

```
$date = $_POST['daterange'];
$daterange = explode("to",$date);
$name = $_POST['name'];

$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select($name)
    ->from('YOUR_TABLE_NAME')
    ->where(['>', start_date', $daterange[0] ])
    ->where(['<', start_date', $daterange[1] ])
    ->all();

print_r($data)
```

Comment: $name bring select query in it itself

Comment: I can't still find the solution